# Build node-webkit with just the functionalities I want

Tags: node.js, chromium, node-webkit

I need a systray for a personal node project. 
I just found node-webkit which have that functionality in node.

So I'd want to build node-webkit without chromium. 
Is it possible? because, it said in [the doc](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Building-node-webkit) that "node-webkit is a part of a customed chromium" 
If not, is there a way to make nw.exe lighter as possible?

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can, if you look at the Node Webkit source code, you'll see that components like system tray are written in good old C++, so nothing prevents you from ripping out the bits you do not need.

That being said, are you sure you want to go this way? An installer for a Node Webkit-based application I wrote weighs in at under 30mb in total.  For me, it's just not worth the effort to try and rip out bits I do not need.

Comment: If you're suggesting that it's just not worth the effort to try and rip out bits in **node-webkit**, what would you prefer while making a windows app with a custom UI? Please elaborate as it may be helpful.

Comment: Looking at the original question, the OP wanted to rip out the entire embedded Chromium, not just little bits of Node Webkit. That is not a trivial exercise, in my humble opinion.  To build a Windows application with a custom UI, I'd use Node WebKit as-is, that's exactly what it's great for.  I have done exactly that, and it works brilliantly.